# conda dependencies file r model in azure machine learning

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I understand what the entry script/scoring script is and does. See [here](https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/articles/deploying-models.html) as an example. As I struggle to expose my deployed model via code as described [here](https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/articles/train-and-deploy-first-model.html) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535014/deploy-model-to-azure-machine-learning-via-azuremlsdk)), I am trying to use the UI ml.azure.com instead. I am a bit puzzled by the mandatory dependency: conda dependencies file:

[image]

I have an R model but clearly this is a Python thing. What shall I use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conda is actually not just a Python thing, you might be thinking of pip?

Conda is a package & environment manager for nearly any kind of package, provided that it has been uploaded to anaconda. So you *can* use anaconda (and conda environment files) for R projects.

The trouble is that the `azuremlsdk` CRAN package is not hosted as an anaconda package, but is probably needed for the scoring service. Worth using a file like below to see what it works.

If it doesn't work, then I agree that this UI needs to generalized to better support R model deployment scenarios.

It is also possible to add the `azuremlsdk` CRAN package to anaconda, but that requires [some extra work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36653411/3842610), but ideally you shouldn't have to require this much manual effort.

`environment.yml`

Here's an example conda dependencies file for R.

```yaml
name: scoring_environment
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - r-base=3.6.1
  - r-essentials=3.6.0
  # whatever other dependencies you have
  - r-tidyverse=1.2.1
  - r-caret=6.0_83
```

Comment: oh yes you are right about conda. I will try this.

Comment: If we are doing it for Python the dependencies for R will change to corresponding dependencies in Python, right? And what is `channels` here. Should it be default always?

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar yep! You shouldn't need to worry about `channels` yet, but I strongly recommend that you read through [anaconda's Managing Environments docs page](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) and get familiar with conda in general. `conda` is great but frustrating at times, but knowing it well will save your a lot of future headaches!